Allow running .NET 8 app with .NET 6 runtime
Is there a way to allow running a .NET 8 app with only a .NET 6 and .NET 7 runtime installed? Assuming the app doesn't use any new .NET 8 only features.
I realize this is not a good practice, but I am running in an environment where I cannot control this...

have you considered publishing a self contained app? you dont have to depend on the runtime installed on the system.

Yes, but it requires me to publish one version for each platform supported which I hoped to avoid.

Another way you could choose is using docker, which you don't need to install any other runtime or environment related, just create the docker file and publish it with the docker.

As KY1 said, if you don't fallback to the lower version, the only way you could choose is using the self-contained application.
When publishing you could choose the self-contained it will let you choose which target-runtime like below image shows.

But use self-contained which will make your application not cross-platform, since it will generate the runtime needed dll during the publishing which let your application could work inside no-runtime environment.
